# R stars read_ncdf returns "vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)" when proxy = TRUE

Tags: r, stars

My question involves an error when trying to read a large dataset, so I'm not sure of the best way to provide a reproducible example.

I am trying to read a large netcdf file into R as a stars proxy object.  The data is from the European Space Agency CCI Land Cover dataset - which can be downloaded [here](http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/download.php).

My understanding was that setting proxy = TRUE should allow the data to be loaded as a stars proxy object.  However, If I use:

```
library(stars)
cci = stars::read_ncdf("filename", proxy = TRUE)
```

I still receive an error: `Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)`

Has anyone worked with this dataset before?

As a workaround I can just read it with `terra::rast()` then convert this to stars with `st_as_stars()` but I'd prefer to skip this step and read the full dataset in as a stars object.  I'm still getting my head around the stars way of doing things but I think this should make my workflow easier down the track.

Comment: Where does your "understanding" of passing "proxy=TRUE" come from? Because the help page for read_ncdf doesn't mention it. Its an option to `read_stars` but not `read_ncdf`.

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman. But the stars documentation indicates that reading as a proxy object is an option for read_ncdf().  https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/reference/read_ncdf.html

Comment: What's your version of stars? This looks like a recent addition (its not in my 0.5.3). `packageVersion("stars")` will say.

Comment: Ahh thanks!  You are right.  I had the current version 0.5.5 from CRAN which did not include this update.  `devtools::install_github("r-spatial/stars")` updated my version to 0.5.6 which solved the problem.

Comment: Always check your local help pages first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer thanks to comments from @Spacedman

The current version of stars on CRAN does not include the option to set `proxy = TRUE` for `read_ncdf()`.  This was included in the latest update to 0.5.6

Update to the latest version of the package directly from github solves the problem.  This can be done via `devtools::install_github("r-spatial/stars")`